# What is the difference between capital X-bar vs. x-bar vs. mu

Tags: sampling, descriptive-statistics

What is the difference between $\bar{X}$, $\bar{x}$, and $\mu$?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: Simple random sampling.

Comment: Do not confuse notation with definitions.  If you ask, "what is the difference between sample mean, and population mean?" this is a question we can help you with.  These however are just symbols, and while they do tend to mean certain things, their meaning changes in different contexts.  Especially in disambiguation of concepts, precision is essential.

Comment: Exactly where are you seeing these symbols used?

Answer (score 1):

One looks like this $\bar{X}$, while another looks like this $\bar{x}$, and the last one looks like this $\mu$.

Comment: Two of them seem to have similar shapes.